# Excel - Faixa de valores de CEP

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma lista de CEP's, sendo faixa inicial e faixa final que vão determinar a localidade, nomeei a coluna A como "ONE" e a coluna B como "TWO", e fiz um PROCV + SE +E, ou seja se o CEP procurado fosse maior que o intervalo ONE e menor que o TWO, ele retornaria necessariamente o valor da coluna de ONE e faria o Proc com a localidade, mas não deu certo, alguém consegue me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Como vai?

Primeiramente, cabe notar que a maneira com que você tentou realizar essa busca não iria funcionar dessa maneira com o PROCV, pois essa fórmula faz buscas por chaves (valor procurado) exatamente iguais ao valor informado, por isso não deu certo.

Sendo assim, o que eu fiz foi uma gambiarra, mas que pode ajudar: como a condição para retornar o estado correto é que o CEP informado pelo usuário seja maior ou igual ao CEP da primeira faixa e menor ou igual ao CEP da segunda faixa, eu criei uma coluna a mais, em que é feita a validação e a concatenação dessas duas condições, assim:

[image: Busca CEP]

Assim, o PROCV procura as células correspondentes em que o valor procurado é "VERDADEIROVERDADEIRO".

Eu testei com quatro CEPS diferentes e funcionou.

Vou deixar a planilha nos comentários para você testar.

Qualquer problema , me avise.

Comment: E aí Andréa, tudo bem? Bom dia, primeiramente obrigado pelo retorno, eu havia visto um vídeo antes que explicava meio por cima essa gambiarra mas não me aprofundei nela, vou testar dessa forma.

O arquivo que você deixou anexo, ao menos aqui quando eu baixei é um arquivo diferente, baixa uma planilha com dados medicinais.

Comment: Oi! Você tinha razão! Segue a planilha de novo. Desculpe. Espero que ajude agora: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210601m26IbpYi